# How can I copy dynamic data from on prem sqlserver to azure datawarehouse

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have created a linked service that takes the data from on prem and store into the azure blob, but my data is dynamic how can I build a pipeline that takes the updated table into the blob and takes that blob and transfer it into the azure datawarehouse, I need this in such a way so that all my tables are in realtime sync into the azure datawarehouse.

Comment: Any Answers on this??

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably looking for is incrementally loading data into your datawarehouse.

The procedure described below is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview). It assumes you have periodic snapshots of your whole source table into blobstorage.

1. You need to elect a column to track changes in your table.

   - If you are only appending and never changing existing rows, the primary key will do the job.
   - However, if you have to cope with changes in existing rows, you need a way to track those changes (for instance in with a column named "timestamp-of-last-update" - or any better, more succinct name).

     - **Note**: if you don't have such a column, you will not be able to track changes and therefore will not be able to load data incrementally.
2. For a given snapshot, we are interested in the rows added or updated in the source table. This content is called the **delta** associated to the snapshot. Once delta is computed, it can be upserted into your table with a Copy Activity that invokes an stored procedure. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#invoking-stored-procedure-for-sql-sink) you can find details on how this is done.
3. Assuming the values of the elected column will only grow as rows are added/updated in the source table, it is necessary to keep track of its maximum value through the snapshots. This tracked value is called **watermark**. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview) describes a way to persist the watermark into SQL Server.
4. Finally, you need to be able to compute the delta for a given snapshot given the last watermark stored. The basic idea is to select the rows where the elected column is greater than the stored watermark. You can do so using SQL Server (as described in the referred documentation), or you can use Hive on HDInsight to do this filtering.
5. Do not forget to update the watermark with the maximum value of the elected column once delta is upserted into your datawarehouse.

Comment: I want to do this using ADF V1 the steps you have given are well elaborated but will not solve my purpose plus lets say I use the ADF V2 how can I copy 1k+ tables to ADW, using Incremental copy as it builds procedure for each table

Comment: Currently what I am looking at right now is ADF V1 Copy preview technique that has a cleanup script where I can specify my datetime values A/Q to which the data gets cleaned up and new values get inserted into it, Every time. So Ill build 2 pipelines here 1 will run one time and copy each and every data, second one will run after the 1st one that will delete the data for each day A/Q to the datetime columns and reinsert those values for that day everyday. Any better approach then this A/Q to ADF V1?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not used to ADF V1, so my knowledge will have no use here.